# Computing Casimir basis functions for Lie algebra $so(4)$ (via Killing form)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was given a problem to compute Casimir basis functions for Lie algebra $so(4)$. I found that **quadratic Casimir** is $X_ik_{ij}X_j$, where $k_{ij} = Tr(X_i\cdot X_j)$ is the **Killing form** and $X_i$ is the matrix representation of $so(4)$.

Consider the matrix representation of $so(4)$ as $L_{ij} = E_{ij} - E_{ji}$, where $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant4$ and $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with only non-zero entry $(E_{ij})_{ij} = 1$. Then let $$X_1 = L_{12},\quad X_2 = L_{13},\quad X_3 = L_{14},\quad X_4 = L_{23},\quad X_5 = L_{24},\quad X_6 = L_{34}$$
Multiplying matrices we obtain that

$$k_{ij} = \begin{cases}0, & i\ne j \\ -2, & i=j\end{cases}$$

And so the quadratic Casimir (Enstein convention):

$$X_ik_{ij}X_j = X_ik_{ii}X_i = 2X_iX_i =  6\left(\matrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}\right)$$

My questions are:

1. Is it really Casimir **basis** function? I could not find anything about Casimir basis in any literature
2. Are there any other Casimir functions (or Casimir basis functions)? How to compute them?

Comment: I suppose you have seen [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73836/how-to-find-casimir-operators) already.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I have seen that, but I dont get what $\omega^i$ means: a power or just an index? And are Casimir functions and basis Casimir functions the same?

Comment: Consulting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element), I also cannot find what a "Casimir basis function" is; perhaps physicists have different wording.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I performed calculations above via characteristic (secular) equation and obtained second Casimir: $(X_1X_6-X_3X_4)^2 + (X_3X_4-X_2X_5)^2+(X_2X_5-X_1X_6)^2$, all other coefficients were either 0 or previous casimirs. Is that all? There are only 2 of them?